# How do I calculate the cosine similarity of two vectors?

Tags: java, vector, trigonometry, tf-idf

How do I find the cosine similarity between vectors?

I need to find the similarity to measure the relatedness between two lines of text.

For example, I have two sentences like:

> system for user interface
>
> user interface machine

… and their respective vectors after tF-idf, followed by normalisation using LSI, for example
`[1,0.5]` and `[0.5,1]`.

How do I measure the smiliarity between these vectors?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
public class CosineSimilarity extends AbstractSimilarity {

  @Override
  protected double computeSimilarity(Matrix sourceDoc, Matrix targetDoc) {
    double dotProduct = sourceDoc.arrayTimes(targetDoc).norm1();
    double eucledianDist = sourceDoc.normF() * targetDoc.normF();
    return dotProduct / eucledianDist;
  }
}
```

I did some tf-idf stuff recently for my Information Retrieval unit at University.
I used this Cosine Similarity method which uses [Jama: Java Matrix Package](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/).

For the full source code see [IR Math with Java : Similarity Measures](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/09/ir-math-with-java-similarity-measures.html), really good resource that covers a good few different similarity measurements.

Answer (score 72):

If you want to avoid relying on third-party libraries for such a simple task, here is a plain Java implementation:

```
public static double cosineSimilarity(double[] vectorA, double[] vectorB) {
    double dotProduct = 0.0;
    double normA = 0.0;
    double normB = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorA.length; i++) {
        dotProduct += vectorA[i] * vectorB[i];
        normA += Math.pow(vectorA[i], 2);
        normB += Math.pow(vectorB[i], 2);
    }   
    return dotProduct / (Math.sqrt(normA) * Math.sqrt(normB));
}
```

Note that the function assumes that the two vectors have the same length. You may want to explictly check it for safety.

Comment: Thanks, I just was too lazy to do it. :)

Answer (score 32):

Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity.

If you have vectors A and B.

The similarity is defined as:

```
cosine(theta) = A . B / ||A|| ||B||

For a vector A = (a1, a2), ||A|| is defined as sqrt(a1^2 + a2^2)

For vector A = (a1, a2) and B = (b1, b2), A . B is defined as a1 b1 + a2 b2;

So for vector A = (a1, a2) and B = (b1, b2), the cosine similarity is given as:

  (a1 b1 + a2 b2) / sqrt(a1^2 + a2^2) sqrt(b1^2 + b2^2)
```

Example:

```
A = (1, 0.5), B = (0.5, 1)

cosine(theta) = (0.5 + 0.5) / sqrt(5/4) sqrt(5/4) = 4/5
```

Answer (score 5):

For matrix code in Java I'd recommend using the [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/~hoschek/colt/) library. If you have this, the code looks like (not tested or even compiled):

```
DoubleMatrix1D a = new DenseDoubleMatrix1D(new double[]{1,0.5}});
DoubleMatrix1D b = new DenseDoubleMatrix1D(new double[]{0.5,1}});
double cosineDistance = a.zDotProduct(b)/Math.sqrt(a.zDotProduct(a)*b.zDotProduct(b))
```

The code above could also be altered to use one of the `Blas.dnrm2()` methods or `Algebra.DEFAULT.norm2()` for the norm calculation. Exactly the same result, which is more readable depends on taste.

Answer (score 2):

When I was working with text mining some time ago, I was using the [SimMetrics](https://github.com/Simmetrics/simmetrics) library which provides an extensive range of different metrics in Java. If it happened that you need more, then there is always [R and CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) to look at.

But coding it from the description in the Wikipedia is rather trivial task, and can be a nice exercise.

Comment: It looks like your SimMetrics link rotted and now points to a spam blog about shoes.  https://github.com/Simmetrics/simmetrics looks like a better one.

Answer (score 1):

For the sparse representation of vectors using `Map(dimension -> magnitude)`
Here is a scala version (You can do similar stuff in Java 8)

```
def cosineSim(vec1:Map[Int,Int],
              vec2:Map[Int,Int]): Double ={
  val dotProduct:Double = vec1.keySet.intersect(vec2.keySet).toList
    .map(dim => vec1(dim) * vec2(dim)).sum
  val norm1:Double = vec1.values.map(mag => mag * mag).sum
  val norm2:Double = vec2.values.map(mag => mag * mag).sum
  return dotProduct / (Math.sqrt(norm1) * Math.sqrt(norm2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cosineSimilarity(vectorA: Vector[Double], vectorB: Vector[Double]):Double={
    var dotProduct = 0.0
    var normA = 0.0
    var normB = 0.0
    var i = 0

    for(i <- vectorA.indices){
        dotProduct += vectorA(i) * vectorB(i)
        normA += Math.pow(vectorA(i), 2)
        normB += Math.pow(vectorB(i), 2)
    }

    dotProduct / (Math.sqrt(normA) * Math.sqrt(normB))
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val vectorA = Array(1.0,2.0,3.0).toVector
    val vectorB = Array(4.0,5.0,6.0).toVector
    println(cosineSimilarity(vectorA, vectorA))
    println(cosineSimilarity(vectorA, vectorB))
}
```

scala version

Comment: This looks very java-like tbh