# Keyword based recommendation engine

Tags: nlp, recommendation-engine

I'm working on a recommendation engine for a simple application. The user is shown a photo which has a set of keywords; he or she can either like or dislike the current photo, and after 10 photos or so, the system should start providing recommendations.

My current plan is to maintain a term-frequency collection of all keywords corresponding to a like action. The [cosine similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746501/can-someone-give-an-example-of-cosine-similarity-in-a-very-simple-graphical-wa) will then be computed for each unseen image, and the top 10 results will be shown to the user as the next photos to like/dislike.

Are there more established techniques for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Recommender systems are sitting on a wide range of methods to define similarity, handle sparsity, etc. Have a look at [this](http://www.slideshare.net/xamat/recommender-systems-machine-learning-summer-school-2014-cmu).