# can someone show me how to work out simple cosine similarity graphically

Tags: text, data-mining, cosine-similarity

Can someone shoe me how to work out cosine similarity please? 
I understand that someone has answered a similar question before[similar question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746501/can-someone-give-an-example-of-cosine-similarity-in-a-very-simple-graphical-wa) but i do not understand how the end result was reached.

Comment: Use the equation. *Where* do you fail?

Comment: i don't understand the equation is where i fail

Comment: Then you need to get a **linear algebra book** and study that! We don't know where to start.

Comment: on the similar question link that is posted on the question, the best answer shows the cosine similarity of 0.822. all i want to know is how he got that answer from the previous step

Comment: He computed the equation, which is straightforward linear algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cosine similarity equation is

[image]

And in the [similar question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746501/can-someone-give-an-example-of-cosine-similarity-in-a-very-simple-graphical-wa) the chosen answer has computed two vectors standing for word counts for two sentences.

```
A = (2,1,0,2,0,1,1,1)
B = (2,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
```

So we can compute the dot product of A and B is

```
dotProduct(A,B) = 2x2 + 1x1 + 0x1 + 2x1 + 0x1 + 1x0 + 1x1 + 1x1 = 9
```

and magnitude of A and B are

```
magnitude(A) = sqrt(2x2 + 1x1 + 0x0 + 2x2 + 0x0 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1) = 3.464
magnitude(B) = sqrt(2x2 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 1x1 + 0x0 + 1x1 + 1x1) = 3.162
```

Then we could apply the equation:

```
similarity = cos(theta) = dotProduct(A,B) / (magnitude(A) x magnitude(B))
                        = 9 / (3.464 x 3.162)
                        = 0.822
```

where theta is the angle between vector A and vector B