# How to check if image exists in Gallery or not?

Tags: android, android-gallery

In my application when a user captures the image before saving into the `gallery`.

I want to check is there any `image matches` with the `current image` (at least 50%). If any image found get the image from gallery and display to the user.

I am very new to android development. Can anyone help me out to do above task.

Comment: when you capture an image at that time set name then save in gallery and then check from logic by name is exited or not in gallery.

Comment: So if an image with a dog is captured then look for images with a dog on it? Anything else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, my logic should be on  image pixels not name

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a Java library for this. I suggest taking a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach).

If you'd like to develop something on your own, the basic idea is this. To compare two images, represent each of them as a matrix of pixels and compute similarity between those two matrices. If you do choose to implement it yourself, take a look at matrix similarity, cosine similarity in particular. A very simple example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746501/can-someone-give-an-example-of-cosine-similarity-in-a-very-simple-graphical-wa).

Good luck!