# Cosine Similarity practical use cases

Tags: machine-learning, text, statistics, text-mining

Cosine Similarity article on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

I see its gives a useful measure of how similar two documents are likely to be in terms of their subject matter.
can someone provides other practical use cases of using Cosine Similarity ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone give an example of cosine similarity, in a very simple, graphical way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746501/can-someone-give-an-example-of-cosine-similarity-in-a-very-simple-graphical-wa)

Comment: You can build a content-based recommendation system. Just find similar items, using Cosine Similarity of the item's descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a document similarity function in a version control system called Meta-CVS. The use case was to identify renamed files in an imported snapshot of code. That is to say, some third party develops changes to the code outside of the version control system, including moving and renaming files. This work is then available as a snapshot, which is imported (say, into a branch which tracks that third party work).