# Compare Two Vectors (Java)

Tags: java, vector, compare, trigonometry

Currently I have two larger vectors of 50+ strings

I want to be able to compare these two Vectors and work out how similar they are. I think I need to use Cosine similarity?

Does anyone know of any methods that take in two Java Vectors and gives a value between 0 and 1 as to how similar they are?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Cosine similarity is for geometrical vectors, not for data structures. Define how to measure similarity of Vector<String> and we can think about algorithm.

Comment: Please use the improved `ArrayList` class instead of the legacy `Vector` class.

Comment: @tkopec - Phil is correct in wanting to use the cosine distance to measure similarity between sets of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [similarity function](http://lucene.apache.org/java/1_9_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) in Lucene.

> the above formula is motivated by the [cosine-distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) or dot-product between document and query vector

Here's a [Previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520241/cosine-similarity-of-vectors) on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Apache Mahout library](http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/) for implementations of Cosine Distance and related approaches. Also consider looking up Locality Sensitive Hashing for a much speedier alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/** Computes the similarity between two bags of words.
 * 1.0 is most similar, 0.0 is most unsimilar.
 *
 */
public class Cosine {

    public static double cosine(Collection<String> a, Collection<String> b) {
        Map<String,Integer> aa = asBag(a);
        Map<String,Integer> bb = asBag(b);
        double sum = 0;
        for (String word: aa.keySet()) {
            if (!bb.containsKey(word)) continue;
            sum += aa.get(word) * bb.get(word);
        }
        return sum / (norm(aa) * norm(bb));
    }

    private static double norm(Map<String, Integer> bag) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int each: bag.values()) sum += each * each;
        return Math.sqrt(sum);
    }

    private static Map<String,Integer> asBag(Collection<String> vector) {
        Map<String,Integer> bag = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for (String word: vector) {
            if (!bag.containsKey(word)) bag.put(word,0);
            bag.put(word, bag.get(word) + 1);
        }
        return bag;
    }

}
```

Type inference, anyone?

Comment: I just wrote it like that, beware it's untested.